# Painless: Get time difference

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I am very new to Painless. I want to write a simple script to get the time difference between @timestamp and T1 in milliseconds.

I have tried using the doc['somefield'].value and doc['somefield'].date.millis and I am able to access **@timestamp** but not **T1**.

Any help will be highly appreciated! I have posted the sample data source below:

```
{
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2018-11-06T00:20:08.802Z",
     "fields": {
      "T1": "2018-11-06T00:20:07.862Z",
    }
  }
```

Comment: What kind of script? Are you trying to create a scripted field? Can you share what you have so far?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to create a scripted field using Painless to visualize the same in Kibana. I have used doc['@timstamp'].date.millis to extract the millisec value from @timestamp. I need to do the same for T1 and then take the difference of the two time values. doc['T1'].date.milliesec or doc['fields.T1'].date.milliesec does not work. Any ideas how to get around it?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a script field that return the different between `@timestamp` and `fields.T1` like this:

```
POST your-index/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "diff": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          def ts = Instant.parse(params._source['@timestamp']);
          def t1 = Instant.parse(params._source.fields.T1);
          return ChronoUnit.MICROS.between(ts, t1);

        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define start and stop values and return the difference:

```
def start = doc['start_event'].date.getMillis();
def stop = doc['stop_event'].date.getMillis();
return stop - start;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLlTx.png)